# Play a specific part of video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I want to play a specific part of the video using `AVPlayerController`. But don't know how to play. Here is my code

```
func playVideoMethod(path:URL) {       

    avpController = AVPlayerViewController()
    avpController.player = AVPlayer.init(url: path)
    avpController.view.frame = self.playerView.bounds
    avpController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    let translate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Int(M_PI/18.0)))
    avpController.view.transform = translate
    self.playerView.addSubview(avpController.view)
    self.playerView.autoresizesSubviews = true
    avpController.player?.play()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this modifications to your code:

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: path)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
player.seek(to: CMTime(... // add time what you want to start from
item.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTime(... // add preferred end time
avpController.player = player
```

Comment: this is working thanks. avpController.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5, 10))

Comment: This is not working, please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810183/how-to-play-a-video-in-avplayer-for-a-specific-duration-in-swift3-ios

Answer (score 1):

```
func playVideoOfSpecificTime(startTime:NSInteger, endTime:NSInteger){

    let path2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "justin", ofType:"mp4")
    let fileUrl2  = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path2!)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: (fileUrl2 as URL), options: nil)

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoTrackComposition: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    let audioTrackComposition: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    let preferredTimerScale = Int32(asset.duration.seconds * 10)
    let chunkStart = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(startTime), preferredTimerScale)
    let chunkDuration: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(endTime), preferredTimerScale)
    do {
        try? videoTrackComposition!.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(chunkStart, chunkDuration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to insert track")
    }
    do {
        try? audioTrackComposition!.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(chunkStart, chunkDuration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to insert track")
    }
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
}
```