# How to Play a video in AVPlayer for a specific duration in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, video, swift3, avfoundation, avplayer

I am creating a `Video` application in `Swift3`. Where we have a list of `Video` files in a `TableView` list. For each `Video` we have given `Range Slider` option for user to select `Range` of the `Video`. Now I am trying to play the `Video` for that specific range, selected by the User.

I am using below code to start a `Video` from 4 
Seconds to 8 Seconds using `CMTimeMake` but not playing correctly.

```
let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(4, 1)////Video start
self.player?.seek(to: targetTime)

self.player?.currentItem?.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(8, 1)//Video stop
self.player?.play()
```

Can anyone help me where I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play a specific part of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045227/play-a-specific-part-of-video)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try this:

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: path) 
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
player.seek(to: CMTimeMake(4, 1)) 
item.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(8, 1) 
self.player.play()
```

Edit:  This looks pretty similar to the original code, minus the use of `.currentItem` which I'm guessing might be the issue.

Comment: I know it's a subtle difference, but this doesn't use `.currentItem` which I believe can cause issues with the player.  I'm not sure if this will solve their issue, but worked for me.